# useHistory not defined in react custom Hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I want to have a AI Voice assistant Alan AI to be integrated in my react app
So basically want to redirect pages using voice command.

But the problem is that, I want to use useHistory hook's push method to change pages, but whenever I access the variable it is **undefined**, I do not want to use `window.location.href` as it refreshes the app every time,

Can anyone suggest me where I am wrong usnig this hook/ or any other alternatives

```
import { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

import { useCartContext } from "../context/cart_context";
import { useThemeContext } from "../context/theme_context";

import alanBtn from "@alan-ai/alan-sdk-web";

const COMMANDS = {
  OPEN_CART: "open-cart",
  TOGGLE_THEME: "toggle-theme",
};

const useAlan = () => {
  let history = useHistory();
  const { theme, toggleTheme } = useThemeContext();
  const { cart } = useCartContext();

  const [alanInstance, setAlanInstance] = useState(null);

  const openCart = useCallback(() => {
    if (cart.length < 1) {
      alanInstance.playText("cart is empty");
      return;
    }
    alanInstance.playText("opening cart");

    history.push("/cart");
    // window.location.href = "/cart";
  }, [alanInstance]);

  const changeTheme = useCallback(() => {
    alanInstance.playText("changing theme");
    toggleTheme();
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener(COMMANDS.OPEN_CART, openCart);
    window.addEventListener(COMMANDS.TOGGLE_THEME, changeTheme);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener(COMMANDS.OPEN_CART, openCart);
      window.removeEventListener(COMMANDS.TOGGLE_THEME, changeTheme);
    };
  }, [openCart, changeTheme]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // history.push("/cart");
    // this also gives same error

    if (alanInstance != null) return;
    setAlanInstance(
      alanBtn({
        key: process.env.REACT_APP_ALAN_KEY,
        onCommand: ({ command }) => {
          window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(command));
        },
      })
    );
  }, []);
  return null;
};

export default useAlan;
```

Every thing work's fine, voice is detected and the openCart function is ran,
it's just that `history` is undefined

Error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
(anonymous function)
C:/Users/Sachin Verma/Desktop/Web Dev/React-E-Commerce-v2/src/hooks/useAlan.js:28
  25 |    }
  26 |    alanInstance.playText("opening cart");
  27 | 
> 28 |    history.push("/cart");
     | ^  29 |    // window.location.href = "/cart";
  30 |  }, [alanInstance]);
  31 |
```

App.js code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import { useThemeContext } from "./context/theme_context";
import useAlan from "./hooks/useAlan";

import { Navbar, Sidebar, Footer } from "./components";
import {
  Home,
  SingleProduct,
  Cart,
  Checkout,
  Error,
  About,
  Products,
  PrivateRoute,
  AuthWrapper,
  Scan,
  History,
  ItemList,
} from "./pages";

function App() {
  const { theme } = useThemeContext();

  useAlan();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (theme === "dark-theme") {
      // set dark mode theme
      document.documentElement.className = "dark-theme";
    } else {
      // remove dark mode
      document.documentElement.className = "light-theme";
    }
  }, [theme]);

  return (
    <AuthWrapper>
      <Router>
        <Navbar />
        <Sidebar />

        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <Home />
          </Route>

          <Route exact path="/about">
            <About />
          </Route>

          <Route exact path="/cart">
            <Cart />
          </Route>

          <Route exact path="/products">
            <Products />
          </Route>

          <PrivateRoute exact path="/history">
            <History />
          </PrivateRoute>

          <PrivateRoute exact path="/scan">
            <Scan />
            <ItemList />
          </PrivateRoute>

          <Route exact path="/products/:id" children={<SingleProduct />} />

          <PrivateRoute exact path="/checkout">
            <Checkout />
          </PrivateRoute>

          <Route path="*">
            <Error />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
        <Footer />
      </Router>
    </AuthWrapper>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: That hook is used if your app is using routing with that router. Are you using it or just here to navigate?

Comment: It might also be that the `history` does not have the proper value when you use the `useCallback`. Try also adding the `history` to the array dependencies of that `useCallback`

Comment: I had the same problem , thing is that in the alpha version useHistory is removed

Comment: Is your application code properly put within a `<BrowserRouter>`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happens when you are not properly nesting your application inside a valid `Router` which provides context for the `history` object. Make sure your top-level code is put inside a proper `Router` object context:

```
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            ...(components that use react-router-hooks)
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
}
```

Same goes for React-Native: `NativeRouter`.

Comment: yes i have wrapped everything in browserrouter in app.js

Comment: @sachuverma Is this custom hook used outside of the scope of the Router? For example, in the `AuthWrapper` itself?

Comment: I don't think so...But you can see my whole code https://github.com/sachuverma/React-E-Commerce-v2

Comment: @sachuverma What do you mean "I don't think so"? You're using it on the first line of `App.js`'s body: https://github.com/sachuverma/React-E-Commerce-v2/blob/master/src/App.js - line 26. The answer I gave you is totally valid. Wrap your `App` Component in `Router` in `index.js`.

Comment: okay okay I got it, I thought I was calling the function in App.js and I have wrapped it around router, but it was the components inside App.js not the whole App.js is wrapped around router....thanks for help

Answer (score 3):

**useHistory has changed** in v6, useHistory is now **useNavigate** and we can use it as follows:

instead of:

```
const history = useHistory()
history.push('/')
```

we now use:

```
const navigate = useNavigate()
navigate('/')
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I've been searching but couldn't get any right solution most of the solutions depreciated with previous versions of react-router-dom, btw I'm using these versions of

"react": "17.0.2",
"react-dom": "17.0.2",
"react-router-dom": "6.2.1"

Answer (score 1):

If you work in **App.js**, you will need to move your

```
<Router> </Router>
```

of there to your **index.js**

and wrap it like that:

```
 <Router>
    <App />
 </Router>
```

and it should work like a charm.